# how to handling this string output situation in C (not C++ )

Tags: c, curl, cryptography, openssl

I am working on the backend to a trading program I am writing for crypto currencies to access various exchanges APIs, to do this you need to provide an API key and a secret personal key that is HMAC'd with sha512 and a nonce to get a unique value, all of which I have got written. The problem I am having is the construction of the http headers which need to look like "Sign: -128 character sha512 hash here- Key: -API key here-"

I can get the hexidecimal hash output to the screen with

```
printf( "\nHMAC digest: " );

for ( int i = 0; i != len; i++ )
{
    printf( "%02x", (unsigned int)result[i] );
}
printf("\n");
```

which looks like this:

```
HMAC digest: 67a73ea21e54379867e788f62b095f85603def7c82c0de9f0d02e19354627a140e8756e3c46d0d1d168df4a2cce305251b02c771234195cdd2574649faa01ce3
```

but when I try to concat the header strings together to get "Sign: -HMAC Digest here-" the output will say "Sign: -garbled symbols here-" and I assume that this is because printf has the formatting "%02x" but the real question is the data actually trashed as it appears or am I just not doing something correctly to get it to show up.

I am currently trying to get it to print out like this:

```
char *header1 = "Sign: ";
char resBuffer[1024];
strcpy(resBuffer, header1 );

for( int i = 0; i != len; i++ )
{
    resBuffer[i + strlen(header1)] = (unsigned int)result[i];
}

printf( "%s\n", resBuffer );
```

and the output is:

```
�����%�q#A���WFI�� _�`=�|��ޟ
```

I have tried to do it with strcat( header1, result); but that ends up giving me a segfault, this way appears to append the data correctly but it wont print correctly (which I assume is due to the "%s" formatter but I dont know how to split the formatting across the array....

Here is everything relevant to my question, code wise

```
// API settings, API key and secret key for your account
char key[] = "9498fbb723961a42816a10bc559cfda7ded2ed8e";
char secret[] = "687cd29def08a7861446c3b4b9c97996c8472e7dd8922da147d3b1343e52e99125d24ace90729fb3";

// method to use against the API, will make changable later
char *method = "mytrades";

// This is required to replace the microtime()/explode methods to
// generate the nonce value required to use the cryptsy API
struct timeval time;
gettimeofday( &time, NULL );
long mt = ( (unsigned long long)time.tv_sec * 1000000 ) + time.tv_usec;
// C is much more strict than PHP about types so we create a buffer for the
// string representation of the nonce
char mtStr[ 128 ];

sprintf( mtStr, "%lu", mt );

// C does not have a build_http_query as PHP does so
// we just create the string neccessary with strcpy
// and strcat
char post_data[ 1024 ];
strcpy( post_data, "method=" );
strcat( post_data, method );
strcat( post_data, "&" );
strcat( post_data, "nonce=" );
strcat( post_data, mtStr );

printf( "%s", post_data);
printf( "\n");

//sha512 needs 128 characters
unsigned char *result;
unsigned int len = 128;

result = (unsigned char *)malloc( sizeof(char) * len );

HMAC_CTX ctx;
HMAC_CTX_init( &ctx );

// using sha512
HMAC_Init_ex( &ctx, secret, strlen(secret), EVP_sha512(), NULL );
HMAC_Update( &ctx, (unsigned char *)&post_data, strlen(post_data) );
HMAC_Final( &ctx, result, &len );
HMAC_CTX_cleanup( &ctx );

printf( "\nHMAC digest: " );

for ( int i = 0; i != len; i++ )
{
    printf( "%02x", (unsigned int)result[i] );
}
printf("\n");

char *header1 = "Sign: ";
char resBuffer[1024];
strcpy(resBuffer, header1 );

for( int i = 0; i != len; i++ )
{
    resBuffer[i + strlen(header1)] = (unsigned int)result[i];
}


printf( "%s\n", resBuffer );


free(result);
```

I dont think you need to see the rest of the code to tell me what I am doing wrong here, it just the normal curl setopt stuff to reach out to a site but that part works fine ( for pieces of the API not requiring authentication.)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I meant to say not C++ in the parenthesis and now I cant see how to edit the post so ooops, please know that I know that I am working in C not C++ but I dont have nearly as much experience with pure C

EDIT: i got it fixed, so i guess dismiss this message too...

Comment: If you can get it to work with printf, then just use snprintf and print into a char array.  http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf

Comment: Well I can get it to work with printf when  I dont have "Sign: " in front of the HMAC digest in the same char array, the output that works with "HMAC Digest: blah balh" the HMAC Digest: portion is a string literal typed before the for loop to read out the data in 'result'. I need to send the data as "Sign: -HMAC Digest" in the same char array, like if this was PHP i code do  $header = "Sign: ".$result; and it would concat, not so simple with C although i am sure there has to be a way....

Comment: You can concat with snprintf using the %s keyword.  So something like snprintf( mtStr, 128, "Sign: %s", hash );

Comment: You said C (not C++), but you had `int i` in your `for(;;)` structure; if I remember it right you have to declare it outside if you use C.  Also, I am not able to reproduce your problem with icc 13.1.3

Comment: ok ill try what you said portforwardpodcast, I didn't think of doing it that way. Thanks for responding again. 

@XiaoleiZhu the for-loop structure is perfectly fine if you pass -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to the compiler, otherwise you are correct.

Comment: @Xiaolei Zhu requirement to declare declaring `int i` outside `for()` is for compilers using a 14 years old (pre C99) standard.  Many current compilers allow to compile that way but also allow new standards like C99 or C11.

Comment: @chux Thanks for clarifications.  I guess my memory (and my college textbook) was badly outdated!

Comment: @Xiaolei Zhu  C is a long used language and goes through significant updates about once per 10 years.  C11 is still not fully adopted.  You can easily find a draft of the C11 (and C99 spec on the web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form string from 2 hex digits rather than a single byte.

```
const char *header1 = "Sign: ";
size_t PrefixL = strlen(header1);
char resBuffer[PrefixL + 2*len + 1];
strcpy(resBuffer, header1);
char *p = &resBuffer[PrefixL];

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++)  // I think OP wants < len and not != len
{
    sprintf(p, "%02X", (unsigned int) result[i]);
    p += 2;  
}
printf("%s\n", resBuffer);
```

---

Per @alk comment:
Rather than OP's style of casting as in `sprintf(p, "%02X", (unsigned int) result[i]);`
Use `sprintf(p, "%02hhX", result[i]);`
`"hhX"` matches the type of  `result[i]` (`unsigned char`)
It both situations:
- The idea is to prevent a value like `0xFF` from printing as `"FFFFFFFF"`.
- The `2` insures at least 2 characters are printed when `result[i] < 0x10`, padding as needed.
- The `0` causes a `'0'` to be used for padding instead of a space.

Comment: To avoid the casting: `sprintf(p, "%hhX", result[i]);`

Comment: thanks for this chux, this solved my problem perfectly, Ill be using this solution in the future, I don't know if this will be answered but is there a performance difference between using the casting and not? I only ask because I assume the that formatting string "%02hhX" is going to convert the unsigned char data to 2 digit hex data which would be converted to an unsigned int first right? Isn't the same thing written differently? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Asphyxiated `printf()` is a black hole of CPU time.  I doubt if you will find significant performance amongst the ideas you presented.  When passed a `char`, `printf()` will always get a integer promoted to an int/unsigned.  It gets this promoted value before the format is analyzed.  The "hh" tells printf to cast that `int` (or any `int`) to a `char`.  Try `printf("%X %X %hhX %hhX\n", 0xFFF0, (char) 0xF0, 0xFFF0, (char) 0xF0);` to see some differences.   Try predicting before running.